# Changing ListBoxItem data according to item IsSelected Property

Tags: wpf, datatemplate

i have a user control that is based on the ListBox.
that DataTemplate is with Canvas that can be shown or hide.
when the user click on the ListBoxItem it should be selected (show canvas)
and another click should hide the canvas.

i use a converter that show / hide the canvas according to my data object (device, see below)

how can i change the my data object (device) according to ListBoxItem IsSelected ?
( it should be toggled between item select=true, and another click select=false)

thanks, Avi

the DataTemplate:

```
  <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="12" Margin="3"/>                    
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Location}" FontSize="10" Margin="1"/>
            <Canvas x:Name="canvas1" 
                Visibility="{Binding SelectedToggle, Converter={StaticResource MYVisabilityConverter}}"
                IsHitTestVisible="False" >
                <Image Source="/Resources/Images/Bubble.png" Width="100"/>
            </Canvas>

        </StackPanel>
```

the object that binds to the DataTemplate:

```
public class Device : Notifier
{

   public Device()
    {          
    }

    public Device(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;          
    }

    private Point location;
    /// <summary>
    /// the device location
    /// </summary>
    public Point Location
    {
        get { return location; }
        set { location = value; OnPropertyChanged("Location"); }
    }

    string name;
    /// <summary>
    /// the device Name
    /// </summary>
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; OnPropertyChanged("Name"); }
    }


    bool selectedToggle = false;
    /// <summary>
    /// toggle between select and Un select of the device
    /// </summary>
    public bool SelectedToggle
    {
        get { return selectedToggle; }
        set { selectedToggle = value; OnPropertyChanged("SelectedToggle"); }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the DataTemplate you posted is the ListBox's ItemTemplate, you can use a `RelativeSource` binding to get the ListBoxItem's `IsSelected` value

```
<Canvas x:Name="canvas1" 
        IsHitTestVisible="False"
        Visibility="{Binding 
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, 
            Path=IsSelected, 
            Converter={StaticResource MYVisabilityConverter}}">

</Canvas>
```

If you want to keep the value of `IsSelected` in your ViewModel, I'd use a Style setter for the `ListBoxItem`.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding SelectedToggle}" />
</Style>
```

Comment: Hi Rachel, there is some problem with this solution, since the SelectedToggle should be changed some how. one place i can think about is the VisabilityConverter class, but how do i pass the device item ? ( i can pass ListBoxItem).

Comment: @Avi This is assuming that the `DataTemplate` you posted is for the `ListBoxItems`. If that is the case, you can use a Style in my answer to bind the `ListBoxItem.IsSelected` to `ToggleSelected`, so anytime you select a `ListBoxItem`, it will toggle it's `ToggleSelected` property.